# Difference between dot and asterisk in find command

Tags: find, synology

I have a Synology NAS, which uses a customised Linux for its OS.
Using the `find` command, I am trying to list the files modified since about 25 days, with some exclusions, within a particular directory.

I noticed that when I use a "*" instead of a "." after `find`, the result seems different. See the commands below:

```
find . ! -path "*@eaDir*" -type f ! -iname ".DS_Store" ! -iname "Thumbs.db" -mtime -25

find * ! -path "*@eaDir*" -type f ! -iname ".DS_Store" ! -iname "Thumbs.db" -mtime -25
```

When I used a ".", I get **some** output after quite a long time.
When I replaced the "." by a "*", I started getting **more** results very quickly and they were different than when using a ".".

I used `ls -al` to check whether the results when using a "*" were correct, ie, whether the modified date/time of the files were within the last 25 days and indeed that was the case.

Can anyone tell me why the results are different?

Answer (score 5):

In:

```
find * ...
```

as a shell command line, `*` is a glob that is expanded by the shell to the (lexically sorted) list of non-hidden entries in the current directory (with some shells, that would be only the entries that contain only valid characters as `*` as a pattern means 0 or more *characters*).

So, if the current directory contains these entries:

- `.`
- `..`
- `.htaccess`
- `file.txt`
- `-foo-`

`find` will be called with these arguments: `find`, `-foo-`, `file.txt` (and `...`). `find` will most likely complain about that `-foo-` that is an invalid option or predicate.

Even if you use:

```
find -- * ...
```

That won't work properly for files named `-anything` or `!` or `(`... as `--` only tells `find` to stop looking for options (like `-L`, `-H`) not for predicates.

You could use:

```
find ./* ...
```

to avoid the problems, but then again, that would omit hidden files, could omit files with invalid characters or break (with *arg list too long*) if there are a lot of files in the current directory.

With:

```
find . ...
```

You only pass `.` to `find`. `.` is the current directory. Then it's `find`, not the shell that will look for files in there (includes `.` at depth 0, all the entries except `.` and `..` (other hidden entries included) at depth 1, and all other entries for subdirectories (still excluding `.` and `..`) recursively.

You'd only want to use:

```
find ./* ...
```

If you wanted the list of files at depth 1 (and depth 1 only) to be sorted and wanted to exclude hidden files at depth 1 (and again at depth 1 only). Which would be very unlikely.

If you want to exclude hidden files, add a `! -name '.*'` Or `-name '[!.]*'` (though beware of file names with invalid characters, and that would also include the top level directory given to `find` `.` which happens to match that pattern).

If you wanted sorting at every level, you'd probably want to resort to `zsh` and its recursive globbing with glob qualifiers.

The reason you're getting different results is most probably that in `find *`, find starts by looking (is being told to look) into the first file or directory in the current directory *in alphabetical order*, and with `find .`, it looks at `.` itself but  then next the first file or directory in there in a different order (could be the order that entries are stored in the directory, but some `find` implementations also sort the list by inode number as an attempt to minimise disk head seeks).

BTW, a better way to write your command would probably be:

```
find . \( -name @eaDir -o -iname .DS_Store -o -iname Thumbs.db \) \
  -prune -o -mtime -25 -type f -print
```

That is tell `find` to ignore those directories and their content altogether (not even attempt to look inside  them).

Comment: Thanks a lot Stéphane. Please confirm that your suggested improved command is correct: @eaDir are directories located in different places, while .DS_Store and Thumbs.db are files. Thanks again.

Comment: @EEMRT, yes it's fine to `-prune` files even if they are not of type _directory_. Here, because they are selected on the left of the `-o`, they will not be considered for the right side (for the `-mtime -print`).

Answer (score 1):

The dot signifies the current directory.  It is common to use it as the starting PATH for `find`.

The unadorned asterisk will be expanded by the shell **before** `find` executes into the contents of the current directory.  This is called "globbing".  To see the effect, do:

```
echo *
```

Undoubtedly, `find * ...` isn't what you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why is the find command taking very long to give some output when using "." compared to when using "*"? Will the results eventually be the same?